# How to suppress Rails console/irb outputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb

I was testing some DB entries in our production server in Rails Console where almost all the commands were producing a huge number of lines of output and causing the ssh channel to hang.

Is there a way to suppress the console/irb screenfuls?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

You can append `; nil` to your statements.

Example:

```
users = User.all; nil
```

`irb` prints the *return value* of the last executed statement; thus in this case it'll print only `nil` since `nil` is the last executed valid statement.

Comment: Awesome, an even shorter way is semi-colon followed by an object like `users = User.all; 0`

Comment: This only works for returned objects, not work of p and puts.

Comment: its just a hack, you can just use count, like `Users.all.count`, only one line output, and if you want to store output in variable can be done like this `users = User.all; Users.all.count`

Answer (score 34):

In search of a solution how to silence the irb/console output, I also found an answer at [austinruby.com](http://web.archive.org/web/20130912124405/http://austinruby.com/2006/10/6/quieting-irb-s-return-value):

silence irb:

```
conf.return_format = ""
```

default output:

```
conf.return_format = "=> %s\n"
```

limit to eg 512 chars:

```
conf.return_format = "=> limited output\n %.512s\n"
```

Comment: Very useful. Any chance there's a way to set this while opening irb/rails console, i.e. alias a parameter in?

Comment: You could try putting it into $HOME/.irbrc

Answer (score 9):

```
irb --simple-prompt --noecho
```

- `--simple-prompt` -  Uses a simple prompt - just `>>`
- `--noecho` -  Suppresses the result of operations

Answer (score 9):

running the following within irb works for me:

```
irb_context.echo = false
```

Answer (score 8):

Here, add this to your ~/.irbrc:

```
require 'ctx'
require 'awesome_print'

module IRB
  class Irb    
    ctx :ap do
      def output_value()
        ap(@context.last_value)
      end
    end
    ctx :puts do
      def output_value()
        puts(@context.last_value)
      end
    end
    ctx :p do
      def output_value()
        p(@context.last_value)
      end
    end
    ctx :quiet do
      def output_value()
      end
    end
  end
end

def irb_mode(mode)
  ctx(mode) { irb }
end
```

(Note: You must install the `ctx` gem first, though `awesome_print` is optional, of course.)

Now when you are on any console that uses irb, you can do the following:

**Normal mode:**

```
irb(main):001:0> { this:'is a complex object', that:[ { will:'probably'}, { be:'good to read' } ], in:{ some:{ formatted:'way'} } }

=> {:this=>"is a complex object", :that=>[{:will=>"probably"}, {:be=>"good to read"}], :in=>{:some=>{:formatted=>"way"}}}
```

...yep, just what you expect.

**`awesome_print` mode:**

```
irb(main):002:0> irb_mode(:ap)
irb#1(main):001:0> { this:'is a complex object', that:[ { will:'probably'}, { be:'good to read' } ], in:{ some:{ formatted:'way'} } }

=> {
    :this => "is a complex object",
    :that => [
        [0] {
            :will => "probably"
        },
        [1] {
            :be => "good to read"
        }
    ],
      :in => {
        :some => {
            :formatted => "way"
        }
    }
}
```

...wow, now everything is printing out awesomely!  :)

**Quiet mode:**

```
irb#1(main):002:0> irb_mode(:quiet)
irb#1(main):001:0> { this:'is a complex object', that:[ { will:'probably'}, { be:'good to read' } ], in:{ some:{ formatted:'way'} } }
irb#1(main):002:0>
```

... whoah, no output at all?  Nice.

Anyways, you can add whatever mode you like, and when you're finished with that mode, just `exit` out or it, and you'll be back in the previous mode.

Hope that was helpful!  :)

Answer (score 4):

#### Supress Output, In General

Also, depending on your needs, have a look at using `quietly` or `silence_stream` for suppressing output in general, not just in the irb/console:

```
silence_stream(STDOUT) do
  users = User.all
end
```

**NOTE: `silence_stream` removed in Rails 5+.**

**NOTE: `quietly` will be deprecated in Ruby 2.2.0 and will eventually be removed.** *(Thanks [BenMorganIO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3369006/benmorganio)!)*

*More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20861482/293280).*

#### Work Around for Rails 5+.

As mentioned above, `silence_stream` is no longer available because it is not thread safe. There is no thread safe alternative. But if you still want to use `silence_stream` and are aware that it is not thread safe and are not using it in a multithreaded manner, you can manually add it back as an initializer.

*`config/initializer/silence_stream.rb`*

```rb
# Re-implementation of `silence_stream` that was removed in Rails 5 due to it not being threadsafe.
# This is not threadsafe either so only use it in single threaded operations.
# See https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.5/classes/Kernel.html#method-i-silence_stream.
#
def silence_stream( stream )
  old_stream = stream.dup
  stream.reopen( File::NULL )
  stream.sync = true
  yield

ensure
  stream.reopen( old_stream )
  old_stream.close
end
```

Comment: Note that `quietly` is deprecated in ruby 2.2.0 and is going to be removed.

Comment: @BenMorganIO Added a note to the answer. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Adding [`nil`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4678777/1438) as a fake return value to silence output works fine, but I prefer to have some indication of what happened. A simple count is often enough. A lot of times, that's easily done by tacking on a `count` function. So when I'm doing something to a bunch of Discourse topics, I don't want a printout of each of the topic objects. So I add `.count` at the end of the loop:

```
Topic.where(...).each do |topic| 
...
end.count
```

Same thing if I'm just assigning something:

```
(users = User.all).count
```

Silencing output altogether (or making it something static like `nil`) deprives me of useful feedback.