# How to suppress the output of return value in IRB/Rails Console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb

An example is if I go into IRB and do the following:

```
jruby-1.6.7 :026 > puts [1,2,3,4,5]
1
2
3
4
5
=> nil
```

Is there anyway to suppress the `nil`? The problem is if I put in a large data structure, it spams something an other irrelevant return respond. I'm more interested in seeing output from debug statements I run through a block and have to continually scroll up and look for the real data.

Comment: Perhaps try this: http://austinruby.com/2006/10/6/quieting-irb-s-return-value

Comment: From the solutions below `irb --simple-prompt --noecho` is certainly your best and simplest bet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to suppress Rails console/irb outputs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678732/how-to-suppress-rails-console-irb-outputs)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you just want to suppress long output once in a while, use `;0`, like:

```
a = [*1..10000];0
# => 0
```

If you want to suppress it generally, use the ~/.irbrc file. The IRB.conf[:INSPECT_MODE] and IRB.conf[:PROMPT][your_prompt][:RETURN] control what is returned. You can figure out what your_prompt is by checking IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE]

Example:

```
IRB.conf[:PROMPT][:DEFAULT][:RETURN] = "" # suppress return value completely
```

You'll need to restart irb after changing the value.

Answer (score 18):

You can also supress the output with the following command as `irb --simple-prompt --noecho`.

Find the below:

```
@ubuntu:~$ irb --simple-prompt
>> puts "hi"
hi
=> nil
>> p "hi"
"hi"
=> "hi"
>> exit
@ubuntu:~$ irb --simple-prompt --noecho
>> puts "hi"
hi
>> p "hi"
"hi"
>>
```

Hope you will be fine with it.

I am using ruby version as below :

```
@ubuntu:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
```

Answer (score 7):

From @Tallboy dead link

To suppress the return value in Rails console, enter
`conf.return_format = ""`

Default (Print the return value)
`conf.return_format = "=> %s\n"`

Answer (score 6):

i run the following in irb:

```
irb_context.echo = false
```

e.g.

```
$ irb
> "foo"
=> "foo"
> irb_context.echo = false
> "foo"
>
```

Comment: Note that this can also be easily turned back on, e.g. `irb_context.echo = false; "foo"; irb_context.echo = true`, which can be handy for disabling return values only on certain code sections.