# Hide/truncate long attributes in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

For a blog model I'm saving an RSS field as text under `Blog.rss`, problem is, some of this is rather long and each one prints when I'm working in the rails console, ie: `Blog.last(10)`.

Is there a way to hide output unless I call `someblog.rss` specifically?

Comment: Use hirb: https://github.com/cldwalker/hirb

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to Limit a text output but i suggest trying out https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print.  It let's you have Formatted outputs + has limit option for Arrays/Hashes.

Comment: maybe this one [how-to-suppress-rails-console-irb-outputs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678732/how-to-suppress-rails-console-irb-outputs)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and received some solutions in another forum, which were:

- Use `select` to get just the columns you need
- If you have a very long column (I had JSON data structure from a webhook cluttering the console), consider whether you really need it, and if you don't , don't store it in the table

  - Or, consider storing it in an associated table
- if you need the whole object but just want to change how it's represented in console/log output, you can redefine `inspect`
- `yourobject.as_json(except: :unwanted_column)`

Also

- You could look into: https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print

Answer (score 0):

You can override the #inspect method in your Blog model. This code would truncate the string it prints when referencing an object in console.

```rb
  def inspect
    inspection = super
    inspection[0..300] + ((inspection.length > 300) ? "..." : "")
  end
```