# Hide the output of a command using Ruby 2.6

Tags: ruby, irb, ruby-2.6

I am not sure this is a bug or a new feature of Ruby 2.6, but since performing the upgrade 2.3 --> 2.6, my IRB terminal does not behave as usual and cannot hide outputs anymore. Previously when I typed a semicolon, it would wait until receiving the next instruction without semicolon to run all the code and hide values with semicolons

```
2.6.3 :008 > 1 + 1
 => 2
2.6.3 :009 > 1 + 1;
 => 2 
2.6.3 :010 > (1 + 1);
 => 2
2.6.3 :011 > very_large_inspect_result;
 => [console keeps printing for ages)
```

Using `ruby-2.6.3 [ x86_64 ]` and the IRB terminal from `rails-5.1.6`

What can I do to hide the output from commands ? The goal is to avoid printing huge strings of `inspect` when returning a very large collection

EDIT : I could systematically add a 0 or something after the semicolons, but it feels cheap

```
2.6.3 :010 > (1 + 1); 0
 => 0
```

EDIT2 : what happened previously in Ruby 2.3.x :

```rb
irb(main):001:0> puts 1;
irb(main):002:0* puts 2;
irb(main):003:0* puts 3
1
2
3
=> nil
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678732/how-to-suppress-rails-console-irb-outputs

Comment: Pry suppresses output when adding a `;` and generally offers some nice additions over `irb`.

Comment: You could also do this `out = $stdout and $stdout = File.open(File::NULL,'w')` then when you are done just set `$stdout = out` to reset the output stream. This is essentially like piping to "/dev/null"

Answer (score 4):

Run the below command in IRB terminal.

```
irb_context.echo = false
```

Comment: This will be applied for all possibilities

Comment: Not sure but I think it will.

Comment: this does not work ? I have edited my question to give an example of what happened in RUby 2.3 before I upgraded to Ruby 2.6